# yii Update content in AJAX with renderPartial problems.cjuidatepicker calendar not showing

Tags: yii, widget

When updating content via AJAX, renderPartial.CJuiDatePicker is not loading properly. When clicking on its field calendar doesn't appear.

Please help to solve this problem.

**controller Code:**

```
public function actionEditTestAjax()
{   
        $Okstatus  = 0;
        $id  = (int)$_POST['ID'];
        $newPerson = $this->loadModel($id);
        $newPerson = $this->loadModel( $id )->person;

    if(isset($_POST['Person']))
            {
                $newPerson->attributes=$_POST['Person'];
                if($newPerson->save())
                    $Okstatus = 1;
            }

        Yii::app()->clientscript->scriptMap['jquery.js'] = false;

         echo CJSON::encode( array(
                'status' => 'OK',
                'div' => $this->renderPartial( 'editAjax', array(
                                'person' => $newPerson), 
                                true, true ),
            ));

        exit;
   }
```

**View code:**

```
<div class="form">

    <?php

    $form=$this->beginWidget('bootstrap.widgets.TbActiveForm', array(
        'id'=>'person-form-edit_person-form',
        'type'=>'horizontal',
         'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
          'htmlOptions'=>array(
                               'onsubmit'=>"return false;",/* Disable normal form submit */
                               'onkeypress'=>" if(event.keyCode == 13){ send(); } " /* Do ajax call when user presses enter key */
                             ),

    )); ?>

    <fieldset style="position: relative;">
        <legend> <?php echo Yii::t('Employee', 'Personal information'); ?> </legend>


    <div class="control-group">
            <?php echo $form->labelEx($person,'birthDate',array('class'=>'control-label')); ?>
            <div class="controls">
            <?php
            $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(
                'model'=>$person,
                'attribute'=>'birthDate',
                'value'=>Yii::app()->dateFormatter->format(Yii::app()->locale->dateFormat, $person->birthDate),
                'language' => Yii::app()->language,
                // additional javascript options for the date picker plugin
                'options'=>array(
                    //'showAnim' => 'fold',
                    'showAnim'=>'fold',
                    'changeMonth' => 'true',
                    'changeYear' => 'true',
                    'showOtherMonths' => 'true',
                    'selectOtherMonths' => 'true',
                    'showOn' => 'both',
                    'buttonImage' => '/images/calendar-view-month.png',
                    'buttonImageOnly' => 'true',
                    'yearRange' => 'c-100:c'
                ),
                'htmlOptions' => array( 
                    'size' => 10,
                    'maxlength' => 10,
                ),
            ));
            ?>
            </div>
            <?php echo $form->error($person,'birthDate'); ?>
        </div>

    </fieldset>

    <div class="form-actions">

            <?php echo CHtml::Button('SUBMIT',array('onclick'=>'send();')); ?> 

        </div>

    <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

</div>
```

*

> But CJuiDatePicker calendar not showing

.*

[image]

Comment: I copied your widget code and it works fine, so your error is elsewhere. If the page loads but the datepicker does not work, it's almost certain there is an javascript error. (Press F12 in chrome and look in lower right for the error-count.) Also check in the source that jQuery isn't loaded more than once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ippi have the reason, maybe you need put this at the end of the view "editAjax" (partial rendered).

```
    <?php Yii::app()->getClientScript()->scriptMap=array('jquery.js'=>false, 'jquery.ui.js'=>false); ?>
```

And control if 'jquery.ui.js' it's reloading too or not.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very common problem with renderPartial in Yii. The easy solution is to set the 4th parameter of renderPartial to true so Yii will include the scripts required to display the date picker.

However, sometimes, setting the 4th parameter to true may introduce new problems like the endless recursive loop and some of other scripts not working.

I found a very good solution here [cjuidatepicker widget in yii framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13698645/cjuidatepicker-widget-in-yii-framework)

Look at the 2nd answer. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->renderPartial( 'editAjax', array(
                            'person' => $newPerson), 
                            false, true ),
```

is the trick :-)

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be better if you could provide some explanation for why it does so.